# php can't see pictures

Tags: php, html, css

This is my php:

```
     <html>
 <head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include ('source\visuose\navigation.php');`enter code here`
include('source\visuose\social.php')
?>
</body>
 </html>
```

Navigation:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" />
```

Social:

```
<body>



  <div id="facebook"> 
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
   <img src="../../images/facebook-logo.jpg" width="81" height="36" />
     </a>

   </div><!--facebook ends-->




</body>
</html>
```

Why, when running php I can't see pictures?
There is only a blank box, but I can press on them and go to my a href?

Comment: Check out the "network" tab in your browser's "inspect element" window. It'll show you what absolute URL the relative address resolves to

Comment: this has nothing to do with php, and everything to do with the paths you're generating into the html. fix the `src="..."` in the source code and the images will appear.

Comment: Could you also provide CSS in your example above?

Comment: use full path in the img src

Comment: Both your 'main' page and your 'social' script/page contain a <body> tag. although not directly related to your problem, this will make your HTML invalid and causing weird results in your browser

Answer (score 2):

Can't be sure without seeing your file structure, but this is what it looks like;

Your "main" php is in the server root `/main.php` and includes `source\visuose\social.php`. Since social.php is *included*, the browser thinks it's a part of `/main.php`.

social.php gives the browser a relative path `../../images/facebook-logo.jpg`, but since the browser thinks it's `/main.php` including it, it will navigate relative from that file, not `source\visuose\social.php`. When the browser navigates your relative path, it points to nothing useful.

You should also inspect the source of the generated page, right now you have multiple html and body tags wrapping each other in a strange way.

Answer (score 1):

it has to be issue with the path of the image. In firefox You just need to right click the images and select show image. To see where it is pointing  ( aka coming from ) and check for what is the intended URL for the image ?

And then repair your images path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PHP issue 
fix the src of your image

```
    <img src="../../images/facebook-logo.jpg" width="81" height="36" />
```

and it would work